# moving from vu2 to vue 3

Tags: google-chrome, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have started the migration process from vue2 to vue3. And now I have such a problem: the browser console shows some kind of warning and it is generated approximately 1000 times in 1 second. this causes the tab to hang. How can it be stopped?

[image: browser screenshot]

Comment: You should probably look in your entire if you have that exact method (or check related packages) and remove it or comment it. It's in `consolePlugin` apparently.

Answer (score 0):

```
setup() {
  // your reactive properties
  const rProp = ref('ref prop');


  return {
    // setup returns object that used by template for rendering
    // if prop is absent you will see the warnings
    rProp
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this one is answering the question.